# Yum install/update hangs at the very end, unable to kill via ctrl-c

Tags: yum, rpm, rhel7

So I've got a group of servers (all RHEL 7.9) whose RPMDBs appear to have become corrupted.  Not sure how or when, but no matter.

I fixed the DBs using [these instructions](https://www.cjcheema.com/2018/08/how-to-recover-rpmdb-open-failed-error-in-rhel-or-centos-linux/).  After that, any attempt to install/update/remove software using yum causes it to hang at the very end.  I get the final line "Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager", and then it just sits.  Ctrl-C won't break out of it, I have to either close my SSH session or wait for it to timeout, and then I can kill hung yum processes and delete lock files.  Once I run yum-complete-transaction to clear anything left over, yum will allow me to do whatever, but it still hangs the same way at the end of any install/remove/update.

What I have done:

- Checked for any hung/dormant NFS mounts
- Rebuilt the DB again just in case something weird happened the first time through
- Ran yum clean all
- Tried installing/updating/removing via plain RPM, and that works, but has no impact on the problem with yum
- Found a stack overflow page that suggested IPV6 was causing issues, so I disabled that by setting net.ipv6.conf.[nic].disable_ipv6 = 1

No impact from any of this.  Anyone have any thoughts?